# meteor Jade iteration does not work

Tags: meteor, pug

I'm hitting a dead end here, the most basic iteration is turning me down:

`template(name="menu")
    div.container
        div.menu-container
            each [1,2,3]
                div.col-md-3
                    div.panel.panel-default`

HTML only rendered:

```
<div class="menu-container"></div>
```

HELP!! Anyone??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with Meteor Jade but my stupidity: trying to return from a callback within the template component... used Session to intermediate and it's working now!